# Is there a way in numpy to merge two arrays, using the part that appears first and does not cross?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two same length timeline-like series and I want to merge the parts that appear first while not overlapping.

For Example:

```py
long  = [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
short = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
```

wanted:

```py
result = [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
#             -------     -----------       ---------------
#             from long    from short        from short
```

I have a chunked iterative solution:

```py
def np_shift(arr, shift=1):
    arr = arr.astype(float)
    arr = np.roll(arr, shift)
    arr[:shift] = np.nan
    return arr

def split_arr_to_block(arr, index):
    return np.split(arr.transpose(), index)


def calc(zero, long, short):
    
    p_block = (zero!=(np_shift(zero))).cumsum()
    
    split_index = np.unique(p_block, return_index=True)[1][1:]
    
    blocks = split_arr_to_block(np.array([long, short]), split_index)
    
    def select(arr):
        dT = arr.transpose()
        return np.where( (dT[0,:][0]==1), dT[0,:], dT[1,:] )

    result = np.array([])
    for sec in blocks:
        result = np.append(result, select(sec))
  
    return result 

long = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0])
short = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1])
zero = np.where( ((long==0) & (short==0)), 1, 0 )
result = calc(zero, long, short)
```

This solutiontake about 46ms with a 160000+ dataset,  is there a faster solution？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think any pure-Numpy code can efficiently compute this. Thus, this is the perfect use-case for **Numba** or Cython. You can solve this using a few simple nested loops for loop that will be compiled to a **very-fast native code**:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

long  = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0])
short = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1])

# Assume the input arrays are contiguous and contains 32-bit/64-bit integers
@nb.njit(['(int32[::1], int32[::1])', '(int64[::1], int64[::1])'])
def compute(a, b):
    assert a.size == b.size
    n = a.size
    r = np.empty_like(a)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if a[i] + b[i] == 0:
            while i < n and a[i] + b[i] == 0:
                r[i] = 0
                i += 1
        elif a[i] != 0:
            while i < n and a[i] + b[i] != 0:
                r[i] = a[i]
                i += 1
        else:
            while i < n and a[i] + b[i] != 0:
                r[i] = b[i]
                i += 1
    return r

result = compute(long, short)
```

Note `a[i] + b[i] == 0` is a fast equivalent to `a[i] == 0 and b[i] == 0`.

---

### Performance results

Here are results with two random arrays containing 160000 integers (32-bit) on my i5-9600KF processor:

```
Initial pure-Numpy code:    4153.57 ms
Provided Numba code:           0.51 ms
```

The provided code is thus **8144 times faster**!

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks so much! BTW, I will try to get it running on the GPU, do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I do not think GPUs can speed up this because there is a dependency chain. This is a huge problem since GPU require a code to be massively parallel and the dependency chain prevent that. There are ways to speed up the CPU implementation using SIMD tricks but this is hard to do with Numba (if ever possible). An heavy grained parallelization is certainly possible by computing the output by block for the two possible previous block state but this require many cores since the computation is at least twice slower because of that.

Comment: Actually, this CPU parallelization approach can also be applied on GPU but it will not be very fast nor trivial to implement. A powerful GPU might be faster but I think optimizing the CPU implementation first is probably better. A first optimization is to encode the input data in uint8 arrays and possibly bits.